# What is the best way to add additional libp2p protocols to Substrate client?

Tags: networking, offchain, libp2p

We want to reuse the clients libp2p instance for receiving threshold signature shares directly from our users, for key resharing/rotation as validators join/leave the active validator set, broadcasting, and for other various multiparty computations. Tightly coupling this logic with the substrate client and using non-standard libp2p protocols seems the most appropriate way to do this.

It seems the best way to do this might be via forking sc-networking. Since this is not fun to maintian, might it make sense to add a feature to provide additional protocols/handlers via the sc-networking config?

Comment: Check out the work we've done with [`Orchestra`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/orchestra) in Polkadot, and the network protocol and bridge crates [which use it](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/network).

Comment: It'd be nice to extract Orchestra to a separate repository or to Substrate for other projects to make use of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sc-network` allows for custom notification protocols and request/response protocols to be registered with the [`NetworkConfiguration`](https://crates.parity.io/sc_network/config/struct.NetworkConfiguration.html) when starting the service.

The `extra_sets` define peer-sets for notifications protocols, and the `request_response_protocols` define request/response protocols which the nodes support.

When configuring a request/response protocol, you pass a `Sender` which the `sc-network` logic will forward incoming requests through, which allows you to handle them.

You can listen for notifications and peer events on a notifications protocol by invoking [`NetworkService::event_stream`](https://crates.parity.io/sc_network/struct.NetworkService.html#method.event_stream) and send notifications with `NetworkService::write_notification`, or use `NetworkService::notification_sender` to incorporate backpressure into your code.